# Export tick data when using Amibroker 6.3, 32 bit in Windows 11

Tags: amibroker

When I used Amibroker 6.3 32 bit in Windows 10, I can export Tick data easily. But now when I run Amibroker 6.3 32 bit in Windows 11, I only received end-of-day (EOD) data although I want to export tick data.

I tried to change Amibroker's compatibility to Windows 8, Windows 7, and Windows XP but it cannot work.

There are my codes to export tick data in Amibroker: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D1MTVGIyIOyoj_ZI77BqlQivbBz4kVWW/view?usp=sharing

How can I export tick data when using Amibroker 6.3 32 bit in Windows 11. Please help me. Thank you so much! Have a nice weekend.

I tried to change Amibroker's compatibility to Windows 8, Windows 7, and Windows XP but it cannot work. I cannot export tick data, I only received end of day data

Answer (score 0):

I cannot view the data.

Btw, you need to be careful whether your computer is able to process tick data. If your computer is not strong enough, the Amibroker application can have no response.

If your computer is good, you can try the following proof of concept to do your work. Here is the example of exporting Tiingo Historical Data (Downloaded from Amiquote Tiingo Historical)

**Step 1:**

```
//Get all price data
Filter = C>O or C<O or C==O;
//Add Closing Price Column
AddColumn("C","Closing Price");
```

**Step 2:** Click "Explore"

**Step 3:** Go to Amibroker and click "File" - "Export HTML/CSV". Then, export as CSV format.

Btw, please allow other people to view your data first.